# How to adjust constraint layout to scroll view to fit all screen?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have problem in the bottom layout where my constraint layout does not fill the scroll view entirely(blank space bellow). This is the image evidence of the problem.
In this case I want the gray background to fill that white space below. I tried match parent in everything but it does not work.

[image]

This is my xml file that belongs to the layout I uploaded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.repsol.repsolmove.ui.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="174dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_img_logo_repsolmove"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageBottomMargin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <com.repsol.repsolmove.ui.widgets.RepsolInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:errorText="@string/invalid_card_number"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marginEnd"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/marginStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:titleText="@string/login_title" />

            <com.repsol.repsolmove.ui.widgets.RepsolInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                app:errorText="@string/invalid_password"
                app:isPassword="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marginEnd"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/marginStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"
                app:titleText="@string/password_title" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newPassword"
                style="@style/RepsolText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/repsol_regular"
                android:text="@string/new_password"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marginEnd"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="228dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_fill_rectangle"
                android:fontFamily="@font/repsol_regular"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newPassword" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnJoin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_rectangle"
                android:fontFamily="@font/repsol_regular"
                android:text="@string/join"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNologin"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/marginStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNologin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_no_stroke_rectangle"
                android:fontFamily="@font/repsol_regular"
                android:text="@string/enter_without_login"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marginEnd"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnJoin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/imageBottomMargin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30" />


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/marginStart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/marginEnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />


            <com.repsol.repsolmove.ui.widgets.RepsolDialog
                android:id="@+id/dialog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <include
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                layout="@layout/loading"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this attribute to your NestScrollView element in xml file

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: This works fine with ScrollView with ConstraintLayout as a Children too, fine.